# I've accidentally been working on master, how can I transfer all the changes I made onto a branch reset master to the last commit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I haven't committed my changes yet as I realised that I was working on master just as I was about to commit. I want to move all the uncommitted changes onto a new branch and then reset master to the last commit. I'm sure there must be a way to do this, but I'm unfamiliar with git (every time I use it it gives me anxiety that I'm going to mess something up and ruin the app). I use sourcetree if that helps.

Comment: Have you committed any changes yet, just to be clear and what do you mean by `reset master to the last commit` if you have not committed anything?

Answer (score 4):

If your changes are not yet staged or committed and your local `master` branch is already up to date, you can simply create a new branch.

```sh
git checkout -b newbranch
```

If you need to sync with the upstream master first, there is a chance that your commits will conflict with the upstream changes.  First, simply try

```sh
git pull origin master
```

(or `upstream` instead of `origin` if that's what you are using).  If you don't get any warnings, your `master` is now up to date.  If you *do* get a warning, `git` will refuse to pull, and you need to make arrangements to reconcile the differences between the origin/upstream and your uncommitted changes. As a first step, stash your changes, then proceed;

```sh
git stash save -m "put a useful comment so you know what this is"
git pull origin master
git checkout -b newbranch
git stash pop
```

There will probably be some conflicts to sort out at this point, before you proceed and commit.

Though often it will feel safer to just create a new local branch and commit what you have, *then* switch back to `master` and see what needs to be done to sort out any conflicts with upstream.

Comment: Creating a new local branch and committing what you have in fact will be safer; once something is committed, it'll be available in the reflog for 30 days even if you subsequently completely mess up on the merge or rebase...

Comment: If you know roughly what to expect, `git pull --rebase` is helpful, too. In the ideal case, when there are no abject conflicts, you get your changes applied on top of the current remote.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't committed your changes yet, that's the easiest situation; you can create a new branch where you are and commit your changes.

```
git checkout -b name_of_branch
```

Then add and commit as usual.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to move all the uncommitted changes onto a new branch

`checkout -b new_branch` will create and checkout a new branch without loosing your changes

> and then reset master to the last commit

`git branch -f master origin/master` will reset master to the location of origin/master on your repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 . make new branch from master (git checkout -b branch_name) 
2 . pull newest from master (git pull origin master) 
3 . checkout into master branch (git checkout master) 
4 . check the log (git log) 
5 . reset into the last log (git reset --hard #log number#) ex: git reset --hard oij349efnj43t8 
6 . push the last commit (git push --force origin #log number#:master) ex: git push --force origin oij349efnj43t8:master
```